# How to read the body of the HTTP Request using Netty?

Tags: java, http, netty

Im using netty3.3 version,
I want to read the Body of the HTTP Request which i received. 
How it is posssible through NETTY 3.3.

Can any body help me.

Answer (score 5):

In your [`SimpleChannelHandler`](http://design.jboss.org/jbossorg/branding/Javadocs/doc/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelHandler.html) implemented class, override the `messageReceived` method like following,

```
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        ChannelBuffer content = request.getContent();
        LOGGER.info("Received Message[{}][{}]", request.getUri(), content.toString("UTF-8")); // Printing the URI and message body
    }
```

---

`content.toString("UTF-8")` will give the body.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
((HttpMessage) e.getMessage()).getContent();
```

See [1].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMessage.html